# returning 1st column from table over and over again

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the value of my td column with a specific class (tablecellname):

```
                    $('#MainContent_myTable tr').each(function () {
                        console.log($('.tablecellname').html());
                    });
```

I think I get the correct amount of rows in the table but it only gives me the 1st value (repeated).

```
<table id='MainContent_myTable'>
    <tr>
        <td class='tablecellname'>abc</td>
        <td class='tablecellcode'>111</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='tablecellname'>def</td>
        <td class='tablecellcode'>222</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='tablecellname'>ghi</td>
        <td class='tablecellcode'>333</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='tablecellname'>jkl</td>
        <td class='tablecellcode'>444</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='tablecellname'>mno</td>
        <td class='tablecellcode'>555</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='tablecellname'>pqr</td>
        <td class='tablecellcode'>666</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='tablecellname'>stu</td>
        <td class='tablecellcode'>777</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='tablecellname'>vwx</td>
        <td class='tablecellcode'>888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='tablecellname'>yz</td>
        <td class='tablecellcode'>999</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It only prints abc over and over again.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$('.tablecellname')` selects *all* elements in the entire document that match. Instead, in your function you want to find children of the *currently iterated element*:

```
$(this).find('.tablecellname').html()
```

Comment: Or you can use a contextual selector (my preference) `$('.tablecellname', this).html();`

Answer (score 1):

`$('#MainContent_myTable tr').each` does count each occurrence of `<TR>` however using `$('.tablecellname').html())` will only return the first instance of the class to occur in the html.

You'll need to use `$(".tablecellname").each`